# About getting blank swf after compilation?

Tags: actionscript-3, sdk, flex4, flash

I was working flex sdk AS3 project on windows xp and had no problems using flex sdk in command line to compile my AS3 files.

No I am on Windows 7 and when I try to compile I keep getting blank swf.

my ant version is 1.8.2 which is the latest, 
my java is some 1.7.0-ea 
and my flex sdk is 4.5.1

all work fine. What could be the problem?

Comment: And I keep getting this Warning: This compilation unit did not have a factoryClass specified in
Frame metadata to load the configured runtime shared libraries. To compile witho
ut runtime shared libraries either set the -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries
 option to true or remove the -runtime-shared-libraries option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message add, you've got an issue with some RSL loading.

As it says, you can compile with  -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries to force the static linking of the RSL, otherwise, the application will try to load them from the net (as it is configured in the flex-config file)